# Drupal 8 REST API permissions missing

Tags: users, 8

I have problem to get the `node/{node}` GET request working and I noticed that permissions for the REST are missing in my installation. Enabled modules:

```
HAL
HTTP Basic Authentication
JSON API
REST UI
RESTful Web Services
Serialization
```

REST server settings:
Content (`/node/{node}`) enabled and all options (`json, hal_json, api_json, xml; cookie, basic_auth`) selected.
User (`/user/{user}`) enabled, authentication: `basic_auth, cookie`, formats: `hal_json, api_json, json, xml`.

Trying requests:

```
node/1?_format=<format>
user/1?_format=<format>
```

Node 1 exists. User GET requests works perfectly, node does not at all (empty response or `406: Not acceptable format: api_json`). The strangest thing is that permissions for the rest are missing completely, see:

[image]

Also tried to enable it via `drupal rest:enable entity:node`, went through the questions asked, but when I checked via `drupal rest:debug` all are disabled. Eventhough the `user` stuff works.

Comment: There were a lot of changes in 8.2 to rest.module configuration and tools like drupal console and rest_ui might not have catched up to that yet. The rest specific permissions were removed and shouldn't be needed anymore.

Comment: Ya, I just went though this,  it's explained in the doc https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview  skip to subheader - `Drupal 8.2 & Later:`

Comment: Also, it appears you are using a format of `api_json`, when it should most likely be `json` or `hal_json`.